# iOS SceneKit statistics explanation

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

A dead simple question but docs https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1522763-showsstatistics say virtually nothing.

What's exactly in the stats widget for SceneKit? I have a scene with a single animated cube and I have 'small square' = 2 and 'triangle' = 52 or 50 or sometimes less. I can make some quesses but I'd prefer to just know. What exactly do these numbers mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ◆ 2 ▲ 52

would mean 2 draw calls, for a total of 52 primitives.

The cube can require 2 draw calls if you have multiple materials, and the number of primitives seems a bit high for a simple cube (6 faces can be drawn with 2 triangles each, i.e. 12 primitives).

Comment: Primitives i.e. triangles? I thought it may be 8 triangles per face but sometimes I get 50 as well. :-) Anyway, is there any semi-official documentation for the thing?

Comment: Ok, I added wireframe drawing to the mix and it adds a few primitives but it also shows that there's only two triangles per cube face. :-)

Comment: @konrad: The remaining 40 primitives are the ones that build up the Statistics display :). Try tapping on the "+" sign to expand it and see how they go up to 400-600 range.